# My htaccess file does not show the page that i want

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to show a page that is in another subfolder inside root dir. For example:

https://mysite.co/es/xxxxxxxxxxxx without extension to https://mysite.co/es/site/folder/index.php

But I don't want change the url. The url it must show always https://mysite.co/es/xxxxxxxxxxxx

My htacces file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.co/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /es/
RewriteRule ^page-in-url$ site/folder/index.php [L]
```

is only one page that i want to have this. If the user type https://mysite.co/es/index.php it must show the index page.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If this .htaccess is at root level, then the requested path is not `page-in-url`, it is `es/page-in-url`. RewriteBase applies to the substitution only.

Comment: Hi @CBroe. No, it's not. The htaccess is on the "es" folder

Comment: Then what do you need the RewriteBase for? And what is currently happening with that code, you failed to mention that completely?

Comment: @CBroe the true is that i don't know to much of rules of htaccess. I've been testing to know if its works. When I type https://mysite.co/es/xxxxxx the url change to "mysite.co/es/site/folder" without https protocol and without the slash "/" to the end and even show the index.php file. Just like I type above in quotes.

Comment: Please, somebody help!!!